# Generating binary entries array in python

Tags: python, binary

I would like to generate an array as follows:

```
[[0,0,0],
 [0,0,1],
 [0,1,0],
 [0,1,1],
 [1,0,0],
 [1,0,1],
 [1,1,0]
 [1,1,1]]
```

I tried to achieve this by setting 3 for loops, but I wish to go further to 4, 5, and higher bit-numbers, so the last method would not scale easly to these numbers.

Is there any simple way for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't figure out why you want this, but here goes:

For 3:

```
>>> [[int(x) for x in "{0:03b}".format(y)] for y in range(8)]
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
>>>
```

For 5:

```
>>> [[int(x) for x in "{0:05b}".format(y)] for y in range(32)]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
>>>
```

Matching your formatting is harder.

Comment: shouldn't ``range`` take some input argument in the first example.

Comment: It did when I pasted it! Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product` to do this.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product([0,1], repeat=3))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: Neat. Almost as confusing as mine!

Comment: This has another advantage of being able to use `repeat=bits`, which is more graceful than `range(number_of_realizations)` or `range(2**bits)` in the context of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function like the following:

```py
def generate_binary_entries(n, t=[[]]):  # n: length of bit number
    if n == 0:
        return t
    new_t = []
    for entry in t:
        new_t.append(entry + [0])
        new_t.append(entry + [1])
    return generate_binary_entries(n - 1, new_t)
```

Then

```py
generate_binary_entries(4)
```

generates

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```